# web.js - Line 1 - Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: parse

Tags: next-auth

I am using `Nuxt` with these in my `package.json` ...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/core": "0.17.0",
    "@hebilicious/authjs-nuxt": "latest",
    "@hattip/adapter-node": "^0.0.35",
    "@vueform/nuxt": "^1.4.0",
    "@vueform/vueform": "^1.6.5",
  }
```

I am facing this issue ...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: parse     web.js:1:9
```

Here's line 1 in web.js ...

```
import { parse as parseCookie, serialize } from "/_nuxt/node_modules/cookie/index.js?v=6d634350";
```

Has anyone experienced it? If yes, how to solve it?